# Breakpoints when using linear regression

Tags: matlab, breakpoints, linear-regression, montecarlo

I'm using the code below to check whether X and Y are giving me the same results for each iteration. Essentially, X and Y (1 x 16 Vectors) are only slightly different and give the value for an equation which has variable values that are chosen via random number generators. When I set a Breakpoint in the Nielsennewupadated() function at the equation and run the code below I get that that the values from the equation in Nielsennewupadated() and Nielsennew() are exactly the same. However, when I run the code without a Breakpoint the values associated with the two functions diverge. I am a bit confused about how this could occur. Thanks.

```
no_iterations = 1;
casechoice = 1;

for i=1:10
%   X = MCsolution(no_iterations)
%   Y = MCsolutionupdated(no_iterations)
  X = Nielsennew(casechoice)
  Y = Nielsennewupdated(casechoice, no_iterations)
  if (X(1,1)~=Y(1,1))
    fprintf('Iter %i disagrees by %g\n',i,X(1,1)-Y(1,1));
  end
end
```

Comment: Are the random variables beeing calculated once before the loop or in each iteration within `Nielsennew()` and `Nielsennewupdated()`?

Comment: @mbschenkel The random variables are getting calculated in each iteration of `Nielsennew() and Nielsennewupdated()`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the actual algorithm you are using, but a priori it is unclear to me how two functions that are based on randomness can be expected to produce the same result? Could you clarify that? Also you're mentioning that this might be particularity of the Matlab-debugger. Hence some more inputs on where and how exactly you observe what value for which variable (maybe with screenshots?) and the exact Matlab version could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As values are floating point numbers, they have a finite precision. You should compare their difference against some threshold value

```
if (abs(X(1,1) - Y(1,1)) > 1e-10)
  fprintf('Iter %i disagrees by %g\n', i, X(1,1) - Y(1,1));
end
```

here `1e-10` is a threshold.

Consider the following example

```
> X = 0.037900
X = 0.037900
> Y = exp(log(X))
Y = 0.037900
> X -Y 
ans =  1.3878e-17
```

Two numbers `X` and `Y` look the same, but their decimal notation start to differ from 17th digit.

Comment: Thanks.I'm not I understand though. When I use the breakpoints and check the outputs from each function(i.e.the Nielsennewupdated() and Nielsennew() functions) they still appear to be the same. However, when I just use the code above or with the amendment you suggested the outputs diverge, despite appearing to be the same when I use the breakpoint at the Output Equation in Nielsennewupdated().And they are diverging by numbers of this order 0.0379. Could it be because, for the same iteration, the two functions are generating different random variables that go into the output equation

Comment: Did you just observe the two short, decimal numbers or actually the difference of `X - Y`? The problem with fixed-point comparison mentioned by divanov, already appears in a simple case like `(1 + 0.1) - 1 == 0.1` - would you expect the result to be `true`?

Comment: @mbschenkel Yes, I did just observe the two short decimal numbers and not the actual difference, when I was looking at the values after applying Breakpoints. But, what I don't get is that the values of X and Y upon running the above code _are in fact different_, however, when I see the values for each of them after using breakpoints they are the same. So, it isn't actually a problem of the `X-Y` here that I am facing.

Comment: You cannot really use equality operation for floating point values. This will work only with integer values.

Comment: @divanov Actually, I've realised that the conditional statement is useless as the two methods are giving me difference values for every iteration. But, what I don't understand is **how the values of X and Y can be different (when I run the code), if when I see the values for each of them after using breakpoints, they are the same?**

Comment: Ok, it seems that the floating-point comparison is not the main cause behind your question. I would recommend you to adjust the example in your question to reflect this. E.g. with `abs(..) < tolerance` and a value for `tolerance` that you would expect to be satisfied, but isn't.